# PR on main branch, as a patch for older release branches with differences in file structure

Tags: git, github

I have the following scenario:

1. There's a PR that was created *and merged* on `main` branch (lets call it `PR-1234`), which contains a bunch of fixes
2. I need to apply the same fixes to a few older release branches (e.g. `release/1.1`, `release/1.2`).

The caveat is that these branches are *older* than my `main` branch. Some files may not exist, or have a different name.

So I was thinking that I should:

1. Go to `patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/.../1234.patch` of the original PR to get the patch in email format. Save it as file, e.g. `~/1234.patch`
2. Create a new branch from `release/1.1`, and apply the patch from step 1 to a new branch using `git am ~/1234.patch`.
3. Resolve conflicts, do some manual changes as needed, and merge into `release/1.1`

But when I am running `git am`, I am getting output like

```
Applying: xxx changed: refactoring ClassName
.git/rebase-apply/patch:80: trailing whitespace.
    
.git/rebase-apply/patch:82: trailing whitespace.
    
.git/rebase-apply/patch:136: trailing whitespace.
        
.git/rebase-apply/patch:139: trailing whitespace.
        
.git/rebase-apply/patch:150: trailing whitespace.
        
error: [file1]: does not exist in index
error: [file2]: does not exist in index
error: [file3]: does not exist in index
error: [file4]: does not exist in index
Patch failed at 0001 xxx changed: refactoring ClassName
hint: Use 'git am --show-current-patch=diff' to see the failed patch
When you have resolved this problem, run "git am --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git am --skip" instead.
To restore the original branch and stop patching, run "git am --abort".
```

So clearly there's too much difference between branches to apply the patch. Is this something I can solve and how? or is there another way to apply *majority of changes* from `PR 1234` to another older branch with *some* manual work. My goal is of course avoiding manual line by line change on all branches.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit the patch file before applying it?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options of `git apply` and `git am` that could be helpful.

1. `--include=<path>`

It applies only the diffs of the specified path. For example, `--include=foo/bar/*`, `--include=foo/bar/baz.c`. Multiple `--include` can be used. With this option, we don't have to split a patch into smaller patches.

2. `--exclude=<path>`

Don't apply the diffs of the specified path.

3. `--directory=<root>`

Suppose a path in the patch is `x/y/z.c` while in your code its path is `a/b/x/y/z.c`. In this case, we can use `--directory=a/b` so that the diff will be applied to `a/b/x/y/z.c`.

4. `-p<n>`

Suppose a path in the patch is `foo/bar/a.c` while in your code its path is `foi/baz/a.c`. The filenames are the same and their parent paths are different. In the patch, the chunk for `foo/bar/a.c` starts with a line like

```
diff --git a/foo/bar/a.c b/foo/bar/a.c
```

The leading `a/` is the source prefix and `b/` is the destination prefix. In most cases they are `a/` and `b/`. They could be other characters or non-existent.

We could use `-p3 --include=foo/bar/a.c --directory=foi/baz` to apply `foo/bar/a.c` to `foi/baz/a.c`. `-p<n>` removes the leading `n` components (separated by slashes and `n` defaults to 1) of the path. In the example, it's `a/foo/bar` and has 3 components. `-p3 --include=foo/bar/a.c` instructs to apply the diff of `a/foo/bar/a.c` to `a.c`. However, the destination path is `foi/baz/a.c`, so we add `--directory=foi/baz`.

If the path in the patch is completely different from the path in the code, I think we have to manually edit the paths in the patch.